# JS code from react-bundle is not working with Node 15 and above

Tags: node.js, reactjs, symfony

I am using symfony with react with the use of limenius/react-bundle every thing is working good while nodejs v-14 but when i was using nodejs v-15 and above i am getting timeout exception.

I tried to run the example.js(example file) file that is to be executed by react-bundle(it internally searches for node binary file and executes usinng it)  using
{ node example.js } it shown the out put and exited the code but when using node 15 and above it showing output and still not exiting the code.